# AWS Kinesis order of data on re-read with multiple shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Let's suppose, there is a consumer that reads with multiple workers from multiple shards of the same Kinesis stream. We decide to re-read all the records again starting from some point in time. Is the order guaranteed to be the same as on the first read? I know that this should be the case with reading from a single shard. But is it solved somehow under-the-hood when dealing with multiple shards?

Answer (score 1):

Kinesis only guarantees ordering of data per shard, every time you read. It doesn't guarantee ordering of data for all the shards combined.
So to answer your question, yes the order will be same as you read the first time.